# Create a html mail with Flow workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

While starting an approval process, I would like to sent some details of the current item formatted to a table. I would like to know if it is possible to sent the approval mail with the table or html in the details section. The contents are aligned in the center by default how do i left align it.

Answer (score 0):

Select the “Send an Email” action, then click “Advanced properties” on the ribbon.
 [image]

Click ellipsis in Body option.

[image]

Enter you html code.

[The Guide of CSS supported for HTML email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)